# Make Folder only able to read/write from a certain process

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, file-permissions, read-only

I want to disable the user/admins from reading contents/editing and the only way the the files in the folder can be read/edited are by that program/process. How could I do this in windows 10?

Comment: You can't. Admins are essentially superusers and can override any restrictions.

Comment: Not even some way if I make the program must be ran as admin? or create some kind of hierarchy for the existing users? not possible?

Comment: No it is not possible. Admins can always read/write any files/folders.

Comment: What about creating like a hidden admin-user and explicitly telling the OS to go though this to access it?  I mean there got to be some way. While other admins-user if any are disabled, sorry I really need this for my security app.

Comment: There is no such thing as a hidden admin user.

Comment: If you want files to be private then encrypt them.

Comment: "Admins can always" is not true.  If an admin has no access through an ACL either inherited or direct, then an admin can not read or write in a location.  An admin in windows is not "root" in *nix.  You can even remove an admins right (or anyone's) to take ownership.  Its a bad idea, but you can do it.  I worked on a NTFS security app.. while doing so, I messed up and orphaned files that not even the domain admin could read or remove.  Pissed him off bigtime.